# How to stop App re-render when entering links manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have a React app where it has an App component. Inside this app component, I'm reaching out to the server to check the user's auth status. Now I only want to check this one time when the app is opened for the first time.
I'm also using react-router-dom for routing. Now the problem is when I enter a path manually in the address bar it renders my App component again. The same doesn't happen when I navigate with the Link component of react-router-dom. Because of this behaviour, my auth status sets to false (it is default to false in App) even when the user is logged in. Then it again reaches to the server, and then sets the auth status to true again. How can I fix this so that the app component doesn't re-render and I don't see that login screen even for a while when I'm logged in when entering paths manually?

Comment: This is how loading an app works. When you manually update the URL you are manually reloading your app, which resets any state saved in memory. Persist your app state to somewhere more permanent, and initialize your app state from there when it loads.

Comment: Should  I use local storage for that?

Comment: Redux isn't long term storage, it's still only in-memory state. It is pretty typical to persist your redux state to localStorage, and initialize the store from localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

First query the **localstorage** for **Auth Status** and if it returns fail, Query with **api call** and add **Auth Status** to **localStorage** and proceed further. asat!

You may suspect of what would happen if user manually update the local storage. Since if you send the **auth tokens** on every api. No need to worry about that.

Have a great day :)